# Add plugin from vim.org/scripts/script.php to Vundle in vimrc

Tags: vim, vundle

I am trying to add the BOOKMARKS plugin from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3394 to Vundle in vimrc.
This is from my vimrc:

```
call vundle#begin()

    " let Vundle manage Vundle
    Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

    " supports vim-shell
    Plugin 'xolox/vim-misc'

    " <F6> mappings to open paths, URLs
    Plugin 'xolox/vim-shell'

    " mappings to navigate buffers and args
    Plugin 'tpope/vim-unimpaired'

    " FileBeagle
    Plugin 'jeetsukumaran/vim-filebeagle'

    " ctrl-P
    Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'

    " BOOKMARKS: Mark & Highlight Full Lines
    Plugin 'BOOKMARKS'

call vundle#end()   " All of your Plugins must be added before this line
```

Screen shot of :PluginList:
[image]

ctrl-P works, but BOOKMARKS does not.

from https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/v0.10.2/doc/vundle.txt#L126-L233

```
" The following are examples of different formats supported.
...
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
```

Comment: https://github.com/vim-scripts/BOOKMARKS--Mark-and-Highlight-Full-Lines is the github mirror.

Comment: Thanks FDinoff and yolenoyer.  That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead (found on [http://vimawesome.com](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/bookmarks-mark-highlight-full-lines)) :

```
Plugin 'Mark-and-Highlight-Full-Lines'
```

EDIT:
FDinoff is right (as usual) : the plugin moved, so the right line to add is the following:

```
Plugin 'BOOKMARKS--Mark-and-Highlight-Full-Lines'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Vundle does not support URI http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php
So I copied the markHL.vim file to ~/.vim/plugin/ and that worked.